# Make non displayable data to appear in the bottom of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

Goal:
Any cell that do not contain any data (null or whitepsace) should be always be located at the bottom of the table when you use ASC or DESC.
It should be happening on a specific column and the remaining column should not be affected.
The specific column is 'Name'

Problem:
I do not know how to do it and is it possible to do it in relation to this Cloudtables?

Jsbin:
https://jsbin.com/jacewudaji/edit?html,outpout

Thank you!

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.25/datatables.min.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.25/datatables.min.js"></script>

 

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>  
  
  
<script>
  
var data = [
    [
        null,
        "System Architect",
        "Edinburgh",
        "5421",
        "2011/04/25",
        "$3,120"
    ],
    [
        "Jim Winters",
        "Director",
        "Edinburgh",
        "8422",
        "2011/07/25",
        "$5,300"
    ],
    [
        "Garrett Winters",
        "Director",
        "Edinburgh",
        "8422",
        "2011/07/25",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "",
        "Director",
        "Edinburgh",
        "8422",
        "2011/07/25",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "Jim West",
        "Director",
        "Edinburgh",
        "8422",
        "2011/07/25",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "Sandra Brown",
        "Director",
        "Edinburgh",
        "8422",
        "2011/07/25",
        ""
    ]  
]

  $( document ).ready(function() {
      console.log( "ready!" );
  });
   
  
  $('#example').DataTable( {
      data: data,
      "columnDefs": [ {
          "targets": 0,
          type: 'sortme'
      } ]
  } );
  
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['sortme-asc'] = function ( a) {
  // sorting logic here
  };
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['sortme-desc'] = function ( a) {
  // sorting logic here
  };  
  
</script>
  
  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you really want to keep empty named cells at the bottom and still allow sorting on all columns, you should consider bumping those empties to another table. Overwriting the sort pattern doesn't make sense (to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order` as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Custom Sort</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.25/datatables.min.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.25/datatables.min.js"></script>

 

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>  
  
  
<script>
  
var data = [
    [
        "Jim Winters",
        "Director",
        "Edinburgh",
        "8422",
        "2011/07/25",
        "$5,300"
    ],
    [
        null,
        "System Architect",
        "Edinburgh",
        "5421",
        "2011/04/25",
        "$3,120"
    ],
    [
        "Garrett Winters",
        "Director",
        "Edinburgh",
        "8422",
        "2011/07/25",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "",
        "Director",
        "Edinburgh",
        "8422",
        "2011/07/25",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "Jim West",
        "Director",
        "Edinburgh",
        "8422",
        "2011/07/25",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "Sandra Brown",
        "Director",
        "Edinburgh",
        "8422",
        "2011/07/25",
        ""
    ]  
]

$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log( "ready!" );

  $.extend( $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order, {
    "sortme-asc": function ( a, b ) {
      let x = formatAsc( a );
      let y = formatAsc( b );
      return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0);
    },
  
    "sortme-desc": function ( a, b ) {
      let x = formatDesc( a );
      let y = formatDesc( b );
      return (x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0);
    }
  } );

  $('#example').DataTable( {
    "data": data,
    "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets": 0,
      "type": 'sortme'
    } ]
  } );
  
  function formatAsc( z ) {
    return z && z.trim() !== '' ? z : '~~~'; // choose whatever you prefer here
  }  

  function formatDesc( z ) {
    return z && z.trim() !== '' ? z : ''; // choose whatever you prefer here
  }  

});
 
</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

This uses two functions (one for `asc` and one for `desc`) to provide a replacement value for the `null` and empty string values. You can use whatever text values you want, to ensure that everything in the column will be sorted before/after the strings you choose to use in these functions.

*There is an issue with this:*

The initial display does not trigger the custom sort - and unfortunately, I have not (yet?) found a way around that. I tried `initComplete`, but that did not work. I will update if I find a solution for that part.

---

Update:

In my original code snippet, I had the `$('#example').DataTable( {...}` code placed before the `$.extend( $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order, {...})` code. I swapped them around so that the order function comes first, and is therefore available for the initial display sort order.