# jquery ajax order table based on Search results

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a 6 column DataTable that has a Search feature. When someone starts typing in the Search box the table only displays table items that match as expected. One of the columns has certain values that start with the letter 'Y', i wish that when someone searches all the results are ordered so that the table item that starts with Y is displayed first, followed by all other items that match the search query but do not start with a Y.

Looking to use something like this ready function (but open to better ideas)

```
function setupTable() { 
    var table = $('#locTable').DataTable({
            ajax: '/locations/data',
            "lengthChange": false,
            "processing": true,
            "scrollY": "400px",
            "paging": true,
            language: {
            searchPlaceholder: "Enter Location",
            search: "",    
        },

        "columnDefs": [    
            { "searchable": false, "targets": [2, 3, 5] },    
            {    
                "render": function (data, type, row) {    
                    return (Math.round(data * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);;    
                }, "targets": [2, 3]    
            },
            { "type": "airport-first", "targets": 1 }    
        ],    
        searchDelay: 350,    
        "pageLength": 100,    
        "dom": '<fi<tr><"bottom"p>>',

        "language": {    
            "processing": "<i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i><span class='sr-only'>Loading...</span>",    
        }    
    });    
    return table;
```

}

```
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['airport-first-asc'] = function (ac) {
        //somehow get data and return if starts with Y?            
        if (ac.startsWith("Y")) {
            return 2;
        }
        return 1;
    };
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['airport-first-desc'] = function (ac) {
            //return everything else that doesn't start with Y??
        if (ac.startsWith("Y")) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 2;        
    };
```

Edit #1:

How do I connect $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order with the Search function in the table? This is only activated when I click on the table header column...
what should these fn's be returning? What does 1 and 2 mean as in https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/sorting_manual.html??

Thank you!

Data to look as below (cut it down to 2 columns, Filter on column 1 (name) and order on Column 2 codes starting with Y to go to the top of the filtered list).
so search on sunshine should result in:

```
SUNSHINEA   YBSS
SUNSHINEA   SWQQ
SUNSHINEA   WSQQ
SUNSHINEA   TTWW
```

Html:

```
<input id="searchInput" value="Type To Filter">
<br/>
<table>
    <thead>
       
    </thead>
    <tbody id="fbody">
        <tr>
            <td>ABERDEEN</td>
            <td>ADSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ABERDEEN</td>
            <td>AWAS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ABERDEEN</td>
            <td>TEEE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ABERDEEN</td>
            <td>YABN</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ABERDEEN</td>
            <td>ZXSS</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>SUNSHINEA</td>
            <td>SWQQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SUNSHINEA</td>
            <td>WSQQ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SUNSHINEA</td>
            <td>TTWW</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SUNSHINEA</td>
            <td>YBSS</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use the technique shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68075282/12567365) to provide a default sort order so that values starting with the letter Y are sorted ahead of all other values in a column (for both ascending and descending sort orders). Then, filtering will work the way you describe in the question.

Comment: I would recommend keeping sorting functionality separate from filtering functionality, as described above - but you can (probably - I have not tried it) trigger the custom sort from the filter action, if you really want to.

Comment: so if i add { "type": "airport-first-pre", "targets": 1 } to columnDefs and     $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order, {
        "airport-first-pre": function (data) {
            //return if starts with Y?
        }
           
    } how do i get the strings starting with Y to be first in the table? How to I access the strings?

Comment: I see you want to use `-pre` instead of `-asc` and `-desc`. But to keep a set of rows always on top, you need to use `-asc` and `-desc`. But either way, you would use `"type": 'airport-first'` in your column definition. That declares `airport-first` as the name of your custom type. Then, you have 2 functions inside `$.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order`. One called `airport-first-asc` and one called `airport-first-desc`. It is in these 2 functions where you have access to each pair of values being sorted (see `a` and `b` in the linked question).

Comment: If this is not making sense, you can [edit] this question and provide some data that I can use for a demo in an answer. For reference: [Ordering plug-in](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/sorting).